# Select the first row for each id

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a **query** (`SELECT tbl.id, tbl.data FROM tbl WHERE ...`) that returns data like this:

```
1 | c
1 | b
1 | a
2 | f
2 | e
2 | g
3 | z
3 | i
```

I wish to have query these results to return the first entry for each id:

```
1 | c
2 | f
3 | z
```

Have would I write this query?

**EDIT:** Sorry, I have refined the question - it should be clear now.

Comment: . . Your "refinement" of the question has invalidated answers that were correct for the first version.  It is not nice to change a question after (correct) answers have been posted.

Comment: How do you define "first"?  Generally you need to provide some sort of order for the elements, otherwise they _could_ be returned in any order the systems chooses to return them

Comment: @GordonLinoff - not sure I aggree with that, my question was the first row...nothing to do with the data...the answers are all using aggregating functions because they made an assumption based on the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  tbla.id ,MIN(tbl.data) FROM tbla GROUP BY tbla.id
```

Comment: This will simply return the first 3 rows won't it? This is not what I want.

Comment: Yep you are right. I just want to answer as quickly as i can. First  one is wrong :( sorry for that

Comment: I apologize, I didn't ask my question very well, please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl.id, tbl.data FROM tbl WHERE x=y
```

Comment: sorry, my question wasn't worded very well, I have changed it.

Answer (score 0):

we can partition the data by id and get one data value per id from that group.

```
SELECT id, data 
FROM
( SELECT id, 
         data,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id order by data) as seq
  FROM tableA
) T
where T.seq =1
```

Comment: My version of Sybase ASE doesn't support `Row_Number() ...`